# Can't parse datetime from server in android

Tags: php, android, mysql, date, timestamp

I am trying to get data from server with timestamp format `2020-04-22 22:50:00` and parse it in my android app like `22.04.2020 22:50` or `22 April 2020 22:50`.

But all what I found is how to convert timestamp like this `System.currentTimeMillis()` to Date.

API method is sending this type of date:

```
"started": "2020-04-22 22:50:00",
"ended": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method to parse your date:

```
fun parseDate(serverDate: String): String {
    var sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    val date = sdf.parse(serverDate)
    sdf = SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy HH:mm")
    return sdf.format(date)
}

// This would print "22 April 2020 22:50"
print(parseDate("2020-04-22 22:50:00"))
```

Comment: Oh thank you. That works! I am writing on Java this project so I converted this code to java :) Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

In java it will be:

```
String server_date = "2020-04-22 22:50:00";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
try {
    Date date = sdf.parse(trip_date);
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy HH:mm");
    textView.setText(sdf.format(date));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Result: `22 April 2020 22:50`